# How to execute a command via an open TCP connection in Golang

Tags: linux, sockets, go, tcp

I have a problem with Golang, what I'm trying to do is open a TCP connection with a transaction server, execute command then get the output.

I'm used to send the command using nc :

```
printf "COMMAND HERE" | nc HOST PORT
```

For the golang wrapper in dev, This is my current code :

```
     TransCommand := "printf \"cmd:list_cmds\\ncommit:1\\nend\\n\""
     conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", hostName+":"+portNum)

     if err != nil {
             fmt.Println(err)
             return
     }

     _, err = conn.Write([]byte(TransCommand))
    if err != nil {
            println("Write to server failed:", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
    }

    println("Writing to Trans : ", TransCommand)

    reply := make([]byte, 4096)

    _, err = conn.Read(reply)
    if err != nil {
            println("Write to Trans server failed:", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
    }

    println("Response from Trans : ", string(reply))


    fmt.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(conn))


    conn.Close()
```

It only returns an output saying that TCP connection is open, I use the same logic in a Ruby GEM, and it works great :

```
def tcp_send_and_receive(native)
        socket = TCPSocket.new(@host, @port)

        while line = socket.gets
          break if line == "220 CONNECTED.\n"
        end

        socket.write(native)
        native_reply = socket.read
        native_reply
      end
```

Is there any difference between Golang and the Ruby implementation ? if not can I stimulate the execution of the command using a TCP connection to the server ?

Comment: Uh... The first example uses the `printf` command which is a POSIX shell's builtin. It works (somewhat) like `echo` so your shell example sends a string "COMMAND HERE" without double quotes and a newline to `nc`'s stdin. Then in your Go example you suddenly list `printf` in the string which you send to your server. Is this intended? And do you really need `\\n`s? Each `\\` gets replaced with one `\` so you're literally sending `\n`s to the server. I'd say your `TransCommand` should be something like `"cmd:list_cmds\ncommit:1\nend\n"` or such.

Comment: You see, too many questions arise just from analyzing your post. That is, your question is too far from an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So please try 1) narrowing your problem(s) down. Use Wireshark to sniff the network traffic which gets passed to the server and verify that a) what gets passed is what you expect to be passed; b) the server responds. 2) Isolate different problems and solve them separately.

Comment: Another obvious flaw with your code is that you look at TCP as if it was a message-oriented transport, while *it is not!* When you `conn.Read()`, it might legitimately return you a single byte even if you pass it a 100MiB-worth buffer. So if you really intend to implement some ASCII-line-based protocol over TCP, consider using [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) or -- better -- [`net/textproto`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/). You might look at how `net/smtp` is implemented to get the idea.

Comment: And by the way, why you have tagged your question `ssh`? Is there SSH involved? If so, may it be that you're just trying to somehow reimplement [`crypto/ssh`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)?

Comment: Your first read will exit the process immediate if the server closed the connection, your second read (via ioutil.ReadAll) will block indefinitely until the server closes the connection.

Comment: @kostix You are right, I was so confused, I had to pass the command without the printf or escaping the \n, the printf actually will evaluate the string, then pass it to nc stdin, now the command is executed properly and I get the result back, All I'm dealing with now is how to properly read the result

Comment: @kostix about the ssh tag, yes I was interested in creating an SSH client instead if the current process is not a wise choice